# Android message object PendingIntent, getting null Intent.getExtras().getString("mystring")

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am calling fragment inside the activity on clicking on bottom bar.
the fragment has following message object in fragment.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

      Intent moreSelectionIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
      moreSelectionIntent.putExtra("selection",Integer.toString(position));
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, moreSelectionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     }        `
```

the fragment calls activity and passes PendingIntent. when I get string from the intent using below code I am getting NULL in activity 
below is the piece of code in activity

```
 Intent i = this.getIntent();
    Log.i(TAG, "intenet------->"+i);

    String moreSelection = i.getExtras().getString("selection");
    Log.i(TAG, "moreSelection Bundle------->"+moreSelection);

    if(moreSelection!=null)
    { System.out.println("message"+moreSelection);}
```

Comment: Share your full code, are you adding string with your intent..

Comment: thank you for encouraging others in stackoverflow. I have updated full code.

Answer (score 0):

You must add your extra string to be able to get it. Add it to your pendingIntent first.

Comment: I have already created intent and added that to pendingIntent .

Answer (score 0):

Use this code...

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: i have updated full code. what could be the issue with code?